# how can i have a random csv dataset with 4 columns and 100 rows

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

i'm trying to  create a csv dataset with 4columns 'name' 'age' 'weight' 'height' and 100 rows random data for this columns but my code in first step gived me a one row instead 100 row ,how can i fix this and how can i convert this in csv file?

```
`import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


person="person"
personList =[person+str(i) for i in range(100)]

ageList=[random.randint(1,90) for i in range(100)]

weightList=[random.randint(40,150) for i in range(100)]

heightList=[random.randint(140,210) for i in range(100)]

raw_data={'Name':[personList],
          'Age':[ageList],
          'Weight':[weightList],
          'Height':[heightList]}
df = pd.DataFrame([raw_data])

print(df)`
```

Comment: this is my output:
                                                 Age                        ...                                                                     Weight
0  [[43, 32, 57, 60, 19, 56, 53, 56, 51, 5, 75, 7...                        ...                          [[86, 136, 126, 131, 74, 150, 132, 132, 68, 12...

[1 rows x 4 columns]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pass the values in as "lists of lists", ie remove the outer `[ ]` :

```
raw_data={'Name': personList,
          'Age': ageList,
          'Weight': weightList,
          'Height': heightList}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
```

To output as csv use:

```
df.to_csv('./filename.csv')
```

[out]

```
        Name  Age  Weight  Height
0    person0   23      59     158
1    person1   50      66     199
2    person2   18     100     183
3    person3    4      60     144
4    person4   14     123     188
5    person5   12      40     141
6    person6   44      65     171
7    person7   50      96     166
8    person8   82     114     166
9    person9   86     142     178
10  person10   51      93     142
11  person11    1      59     166
12  person12   61     138     152
13  person13   46      92     164
14  person14   25     103     195
15  person15   24      42     150
16  person16   33     123     186
17  person17   44      64     193
18  person18   40     118     159
19  person19   25     134     196
20  person20    5     117     178
...
```

---

An alternative approach, is to use `numpy.random`, where most methods have a `size` parameter:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


person="person"
n = 100

personList = [person+str(i) for i in range(n)]

ageList = np.random.randint(1,90, size=n)

weightList = np.random.randint(40,150, size=n)

heightList = np.random.randint(140,210, size=n)

raw_data={'Name': personList,
          'Age': ageList,
          'Weight': weightList,
          'Height': heightList}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
```

Comment: thank you very much, in continue my question is how convert this into csv file format

Comment: do `df.to_csv('./filename.csv')`

Answer (score 0):

`numpy` is great at building random arrays, and `pandas` internally uses `numpy` arrays. So my advice is to use that:

```
...
ageList=np.random.randint(1,91,100)       # note the +1 on highest value  for np.random.randint

weightList=np.random.randint(40,151,100)

heightList=np.random.randint(140,211,100)

raw_data={'Name':[personList],
          'Age':[ageList],
          'Weight':[weightList],
          'Height':[heightList]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)              # note passing a mapping and not a sequence
```